# Run a sql script from a bat file and divide the result set in two csv files based on a flag

Tags: sql-server, cmd

**Story:** I have a bat file being run weekly that generates a CSV file dump based on a query.

I would like to separate the file in two based on a value in a column. That column is a flag with binary values (0,1)

**Objective:** My goal is to create two CSV files where the content is based on this:

CSV 1:

```
select *
from table
where flag = 0
```

CSV 2:

```
select *
from table
where flag = 1
```

**My current bat file looks like this:**

How can I modify it without having to create two SQL query files because they're pretty huge.

```
sqlcmd -S ServerName -i "pathOfSqlQuery" -s , -W -u |findstr /v /c:"---" > "DestinationFilename.csv"
```

Comment: Run the sqlcmd twice. Once for each query.  You don't really need the batch-file tag for this question.  It seems you are looking for help on how to query the database.

Comment: See the `-q` option for the [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: if run the sqlcmd twice im essential running the same query twice which is precisely what i want to avoid

Comment: @jwdonahue how do i combine the -q option with my -i command running a sql file ?

Comment: No, you run two different queries.

Comment: @jwdonahue can you provide an example ?

Comment: No.  You haven't provided an [mcve].  Too many unknowns for anybody to give you much help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSIS available on the server, I would use an SSIS job. Create a job with the query as your data source and in the next step do a conditional split into each file based on your criteria. You can take the exact columns you want into each file (for instance you can exclude the flag column if you don't need it) and the query is only run once. This can be scheduled using SQL Agent.

There's a bit of learning to SSIS but the control and flexibility you gain will be worth it.

Comment: i dont have permissions to create jobs

Comment: Can you create a stored procedure?